# Update just loaded fields with mongocsharpdriver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

So in my database assume I have a document similar to...

```
{
  _id : 12334,
  name: "MyName",
  children: [],
  age: 102
}
```

However in my model I simply want

```
public class User
{
  public int Id { get; set;
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to be able to do as shown below...

```
var user = _collection.FindAs<User>(Query.Eq("_id", 1234));
user.Name = "Changed Name";
_collection.Update(user);
```

I am aware of Save, but this does not do what I want, Save would replace the entire saved document with the one I passed it, resulting in "children", and "age" field being deleted!

At present I'm thinking the only way to do this is to iterate over all fields and create the appropriate Update document from it, this is a bit of a pain and I was hoping there was a less error prone way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have 2 options:

1. Get the entry (user in this case), change its properties and save it back by using save or upsert.
2. Use an update command and specify (type safely) which fields to change and how.

I would go with the second option because I think it's a more "NoSQL" way